# Ryan Florence's rf.slideshow not working properly with JqueryUI 10 - is there a fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget

I have included the necessary files, then tried to run the slideshow. It seems to work visually, but:

```
var $x = $("#mydiv").slideshow();
```

returns *undefined* instead of the object that controls the show.  When I use jqui 1.8, everything's fine.  The problem seems to be the *widget* part, that is, **jquery.ui.widget.js** - so before I dive into fixing it, I'd like to ask 2 things:

1. Has anyone encountered the same problem?
2. Is there a fix?

Thanks,
DK

Comment: 2 things I know for sure now: 1: the problem is in jquery.ui.widgets.js, 2: any version with 1.9 still does the job and 1.10 loses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just set up a <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjUHZ/3/)</kbd> and all seems to work with :

- jquery-1.10.2
- jquery.ui.core (from jquery-ui 1.10.4)
- jquery.ui.widget.js (from jquery-ui 1.10.4)
- jquery.rf.slideshow (latest release 1.1.1 from [rpflorence repository](https://github.com/rpflorence/jquery-rf-slideshow))

Open the <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjUHZ/3/)</kbd>, open your js console (F12), reload the page and you will see that the

```
<div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
```

appears in the console (no `undefined`)

**EDIT:**

I don't know yet why the widget call without parameter doesn't return the instance itself. I'll try to investigate a little more on that point.

But from jQueryUI 1.9 onwards, you can get the widget instance [using `.data()` and the full widget name (including namespace)](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys), which is in your case:

```
var $ss = $('#slideshow').slideshow().data('rf-slideshow');
```

I edited the <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjUHZ/3/)</kbd> to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle!  Yep, I tried the data() way (plus a couple of things).  But I never checked with 10.4 so maybe they've fixed something...  I'm checking it right now!

Comment: Okay, I updated the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/TjUHZ/2/ - it still says "undefined".  Also, with your original fiddle, the div itself is returned but it's not what should be. $ss should be ab OBJECT, able to manage the slideshow with methods like prev/next, etc. Getting back the div itself is a sign of not working.  If you try the same thing with jqui 1.9, it gives you the object as it should.

Comment: I added "setInterval(function() {console.log($ss.current);},2000);" and it shows the actual index of currently displayed image! THANK YOU! Your last line did the trick, indeed it's with the namespace which is "rf-slideshow". Now an important addition is that they've REALLY changed one thing from 1.9.x to 1.10: see http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8155 for the ticket, they've removed a property that RF slider (partly) relies on. That's obviously a problem but now with this data() solution I can use RF slider. So thanks again!